# In Outlook 2003, get display name of additional mailboxes and PSTs

Tags: names, outlook-2003, pst

I've written this piece of code:

```
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMAPI = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
WScript.Sleep 3000

For Each oStore In oMAPI.Stores
    If oStore.ExchangeStoreType = 1 Then
        MsgBox oStore.DisplayName
    End If
Next
```

It gives me the names of all additional mailboxes in Outlook 2010. If I set the exchange store type to 3, then it will return all currently used PST names.

I would like to achieve the same for Outlook 2003 (only the display names as well).

Unfortunately, there in 2003, the store object does not exist.

I've searched the internet and found quite complicated "solutions" for this. I've tried to reproduce some of them but never really got anywhere close to succeeding.
All I want is the displayed name of the additional mailboxes and the PST files... that's it, in Outlook 2003.

Now my question:
- Is this possible to achieve natively under XP / Outlook 2003?
- I'm fine with the additional mailboxes if the PST files are too complicated

I thank you in advance! This is quite an important matter to me :)
So I would appreciate any help.

I don't need a full solution but maybe someone with knowledge that could help me with the key facts (objects, methods ...)

I've read about wrappers and such but it's something I cannot afford to use (only freeware) and I've never used. I cross my fingers that it works with Oultook's native functions :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
Sub GetMailBoxNames()

  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim i As Long

  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  For i = 1 To olNS.Folders.Count
    Debug.Print olNS.Folders(i).name
  Next i

End Sub
```